# Как создать установочный файл под линукс?

Tags: linux, qt

Необходимо создать установочный файл приложения, написанного на QT под Linux.
В интернете нашел много способов сделать это через консоль, но в силу обстоятельств нужна утилита с графическим интерфейсом, например, как на Windows: Smart Install Maker или createinstall.

Comment: Это невозможно, так как линукс — понятие слишком обширное. Установочные файлы создают не под линукс, а под конкретные дистрибутивы. И да, графический инсталлятор считается злом.

Comment: И уж тем более вряд ли вы найдёте линуксовый аналог createinstall, потому что в линуксе такие поделия нафиг никому не нужны (ну, кроме вас)

Comment: @andreymal, *понятие слишком обширное* — скорее, наоборот, очень узкое: ведь программа *linux* не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к gui. // в остальном — присоединяюсь к изложенному.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну это по официальному термину оно узкое, а в разговорной речи оно чудовищно широкое :)

Comment: @andreymal, а вот сами и поощряем новичков, применяя один и тот же термин к совершенно разным сущностям (имеющим к тому же собственные вполне конкретные названия). p.s. по поводу «такие поделия нафиг никому не нужны» — тоже не совсем верно, если подумать. существует ведь такая фигня, как [epm](https://www.msweet.org/epm/). значит, кому-то бывает нужна.

Comment: А можно эти обстоятельства узнать? Очень интересно.

Comment: непонятно что нужно графический установщик или графический генератор установщиков?

Comment: @andreymal я видел много `.run` инсталяторов в линукс

Comment: @eri я тоже, и в любом нормальном дистрибутиве они считаются злом

Comment: маркетологи их любят, вот даже Qt поставляется таким инсталятором...

Comment: добавил про установщик от qt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Линуксоиды любят пакеты.

Самый простой способ собрать пакет - это программа checkinstall. Начните с неё.

Заходишь в папку с проектом.
Делаешь qmake --project (создаст pro файл)

далее просто qmake.

затем make

и наконец checkinstall -D --install=no (для выполнения должен быть установлен пакет checkinstall)

Будет предложенна анкетка.
Создастся пакет под дистрибутив с которого запускалась checkinstall (rpm или deb).

Возможно прийдется доработать проект чтоб он устанавливался правильно.

## Нелюбимый способ

Чтоб создать установщик в стиле Windows можно воспользоваться [binarycreator](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-tools.html) из [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-overview.html). В пакетах его нет, устанавливается через тот же инсталятор [скачать тут](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/).

Плюсы этого способа:

- проще выпускать
- встроенные зависимости
- не нужно беспокоиться о вериях системы пользователя

Минусы:

- занимает много места
- компоненты qt не обнавляются
- сложнее администрирование и установка

Comment: 13 мая - это недавний вопрос

Comment: извините, я смотрел на телефоне и увидел там 13 год, бог знает как

Answer (score 1):

[qtDeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/QtDeployer)

[image: qtdeployer]

Сам соберет все твои зависимости и сделает тебе интерполятор под линукс
ссылка на загрузку [установщика](https://github.com/QuasarApp/QtDeployer/releases/download/v1.1.1/installer_qt-deployer)

Установщик будет следующего вида :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ряд требований:

- Qt должен быть установлен с официального [инсталлера](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5)
- При установке Qt нужно установить QtInstallFramework 2.0 или 3.0